# New MacBook Pro 14" stuck on "Select your country or region"

Tags: macbook-pro

I've got a brand new MacBook Pro and I can't get past the third screen. After "Hello", I chose the language and then came "Select your country or region", but I can't move forward. Hitting Enter makes a noise and clicking on "Continue" does nothing. I can hit Esc and see the VoiceOver explanation screen, then hit Esc again and go back to "Select your country or region", and I can highlight different countries in the list, so the computer is not frozen.
Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a problem with a brand new Mac, take it back to the shop where you bought it, or to any Apple Store, where you should be able to get help, either to overcome the problem, or to return it for a replacement, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

That country/region screen is weird. To select your country, navigate to the correct country with the arrow keys or tab, etc., then hit the spacebar to choose the selected list item.